# jCal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I've downloaded [jCal plugin](http://www.overset.com/2008/05/12/multiday-calendar-datepicker-jquery-plugin/) .It's a realy interesting plugin.
So my question is, when i select days, i get in the output only the starting date of the range like 23/05/2012, i can't figure out how to get the last date of the range.

It do this code:

```
var dCursor = new Date( day.getTime() );

for (var di=0; di < days; di++) {

   var currDay = $(this._target).find('[id*=d_' + ( dCursor.getMonth() + 1 ) + '_' + dCursor.getDate() + '_' + dCursor.getFullYear() + ']');

   if (currDay.length) currDay.append('<div class="dInfo"><span style="color:#ccc"></span>SELECTED</div>');

   dCursor.setDate( dCursor.getDate() + 1 );
}
```

and than i get the first date output by this code:

```
( day.getMonth() + 1 ) + '/' + day.getDate() + '/' + day.getFullYear() + '</div>');
```

I'm very begginer in javascript, so if anyone know the solution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i solved it.

And the solution was realy simply.

enddate.setDate( dCursor.getDate() + days );

( enddate.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + ( enddate.getDate() - 1 ) + '/' + enddate.getFullYear()